# Processing error "Syntax error expected ; but found i"

Tags: javascript, matrix, processing

I am trying to write a matrix library in processing using javascript but keep getting the error above on line 5. I can't seem to spot what is causing the error so any help would be appreciated.

The goal is to implement the matrix product function.

```js
function Matrix(rows,cols){
    this.rows = rows;
    this.cols = cols;
    this.data = [];
    
    for(var i = 0; i < this.rows; i++){
      //assign every row an array
      this.data[i] = [];
      for (var j = 0; j < this.cols; j++){
        //assign every column an array
        this.data[i][j] = 0;
      }
    }
  }
  
  Matrix.prototype.multiply = function(n){
    if(n instanceof Matrix){
      
    // Matrix product
    if (this.cols !== n.rows) {
      console.log('Columns of A must match rows of B.');
      return undefined;
    }
    let result = new Matrix(this.rows, n.cols);
    for (let i = 0; i < result.rows; i++) {
      for (let j = 0; j < result.cols; j++) {
        // Dot product of values in col
        let sum = 0;
        for (let k = 0; k < this.cols; k++) {
          sum += this.data[i][k] * n.data[k][j];
        }
        result.data[i][j] = sum;
      }
    }
    return result;
  }
    
    else{
      for(var i = 0; i < this.rows; i++){
       for (var j = 0; j < this.cols; j++){
         //multiply scalar
         this.data[i][j] *= n;
      }
    }
   }
  }
```

Comment: I don't get any errors from that code.

Answer (score 0):

I found the error it was just a curly bracket in the wrong place!

Comment: Typo questions should not be answered. You should just have deleted it.